# Is there a way to make a while true statement run, but let later code also run?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a program detect when I press W, to move a turtle object forward. However, to make it run all the time I need a while True statement. But, because while True prevents future code from running, my program stops responding because it isnt reaching the done() part of my program.

This program is for Windows 10, on Python 3.7. I have tried putting it after done() to no avail.

Here's my code.

```
from turtle import *
import msvcrt

def keyDetect():
    while True:
       if msvcrt.kbhit():
           key = msvcrt.getch()
           return key

linerunner = Turtle()
while True:
    if keyDetect() == "b'w'":
        linerunner.forward(1)

done()
```

Expected results:
While pressing W, the turtle object will move forward in increments of 1 until I stop holding it down.

Actual results:
Python.exe is not responding

Comment: Maybe with threads or asyncio, your second while True is blocking the main thread. Or you need a break inside your loop

Comment: Note that a `while True:` loop without some sort of delay, with consume a lot of CPU while Python is running the loop as fast as it can. Adding `time.sleep(0.05)` will sleep for 50ms between loops, which should reduce CPU usage, but still leave the code responsive to a key-press.

Answer (score 0):

Add another condition that tells your program to exit the loop (`break` statement), like pressing the S key:

```
while True:
    if keyDetect() == "b'w'":
        linerunner.forward(1)
    elif keyDetect() == "b's'":
        break
done()
```

Comment: This won't work because I need it to be constantly checking if a key is pressed. It can't be a one-off thing. And having a key that would break the loop wont work because by pressing S you'd just end the entire program, so whats the point of having it run in the first place?